# How can i get "token" string in below output using python 2.7 regular expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to get a value of token in below output using python re. Could someone please help me out

I need to get below string:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIIkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIxOWQzODdmZC1kMjA2LTQzNDYtOGRhNy1lMjRkNDZlMWZjZDgiLCJleHAiOjE0OTMwNTA1MxNH0.JBiPb0x4pg_lQXxEV-rbd27qvgm9Q`
```

Output:

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIIkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIxOWQzODdmZC1kMjA2LTQzNDYtOGRhNy1lMjRkNDZlMWZjZDgiLCJleHAiOjE0OTMwNTA1MxNH0.JBiPb0x4pg_lQXxEV-rbd27qvgm9Q","refresh_token":"639d4-b4e0-4c-8645-229b9e73a394","expires_in":604800,"user":{"id":"19d-d206-43-8da7-e2cd8","username":"tej123","email":"mrtej@gmail.com","enabled":true,"updated_email":null,"last_login_at":"2017-04-17T16:14:26.520Z"}}
```

Comment: How about using the right tool for the job -- JSON parser? (`json.loads(..)["token"]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import json
j = json.loads('{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIIkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIxOWQzODdmZC1kMjA2LTQzNDYtOGRhNy1lMjRkNDZlMWZjZDgiLCJleHAiOjE0OTMwNTA1MxNH0.JBiPb0x4pg_lQXxEV-rbd27qvgm9Q","refresh_token":"639d4-b4e0-4c-8645-229b9e73a394","expires_in":604800,"user":{"id":"19d-d206-43-8da7-e2cd8","username":"tej123","email":"mrtej@gmail.com","enabled":true,"updated_email":null,"last_login_at":"2017-04-17T16:14:26.520Z"}}')
print(j['token'])
```